# Equivalent to LINQ to Events in Scala

Tags: scala, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Is it possible to do something similar to [LINQ to Events](http://themechanicalbride.blogspot.com/2009/07/introducing-rx-linq-to-events.html) in Scala? Is this similar to the new Traversable trait in Scala 2.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is - it's [RxScala](http://rxscala.github.io). It's a Scala adapter for the RxJava project.

Answer (score 4):

To make an analogy, it sounds like (in .NET) IObservable is to IEnumerable what (in Scala) Traversable is to Iterable. That's just an interface though. The broader Rx (LINQ to Events) project sounds like Functional Reactive Programming (FRP) in .NET. For Scala, Ingo Maier is working on something like this under the name ScalaFX.